# reading attributes with special names from MS ACCESS in OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbdatareader

I have som problems with reading from accdb database when it has fieldnames with characters like "-", "%", "/" or if the fieldname is "Level".
When I have something like this:

```
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT 'Part_Time_%','Level',Level_change_reason FROM Employees";
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(oledbConnectString);
OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery,myConnection);
myConnection.Open();
OleDbDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

it works well because '' characters cancel special characters and word meening.
This is ok:

```
if ((myReader["Name"] == DBNull.Value) ....
if ((myReader["Surname"] == DBNull.Value) ....
```

But when I try this:

```
if ((myReader["Macro-activity"] == DBNull.Value) ...
if ((myReader["Level"] == DBNull.Value)....
```

it jumps to catch statement.
I also tried `myReader["\u004cevel"], myReader["'Macro-activity'"]` - it totally ignores escape characters.

Every answer would be very appreciated.

P.S.: I can not change the name of attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping of columns names in Access uses braces, `[ & ]`, not single quotes.

```
string mySelectQuery = "SELECT '[Part_Time_%],[Level],Level_change_reason FROM Employees";
```

Single quotes are for a string, so having 'Level' in the select statement will return the text 'Level' as an unnamed column in your result set.  If you try `myReader.GetItem(1)` it will return `"Level"` for every row.

Comment: Thanks for answer but SELECT statement works very well, but this myReader["Macro-activity"] and this myReader["Level"] fails. First time I have used this myReader.GetItem(1), but when cell was empty, it failed. So I use this myReader["Local_Global_Structure"] == DBNull.Value for control. Is here myReader.GetItem(1) any possibility to do this control?

Comment: myReader["[Macro-activity]"] is what your wanting

Comment: When I remove catch statement, then IndexOutOfRange is unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it does what I want:

```
if ((myReader.GetValue(18) == DBNull.Value) || string.Compare(myReader.GetValue(18).ToString(), "0") == 0)....
```